# Trigger to track changes in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I cannot seem to create a trigger. I have tried it the two ways below for the update. I keep getting a syntax error with the insert statement. I have searched forums and web searches for the past 4 hrs with no change. There is alot more code to this, It basically repeats itself. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You. I am running MySQL 5.0 and acessing via phpMyAdmin 2.8.2.4 as Administrator/Root.

---

### TRY 1 (with and without qoutes on all fields and names)

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_classes
AFTER insert ON Classes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into insert_tracking_classes (classID, Title, classDesc, Category, isEvent, picLeft, picTop, picRight, picBottom, prnColor, modified)
    values(NEW.classID, NEW.Title, NEW.classDesc, NEW.Category, NEW.isEvent, NEW.picLeft, NEW.picTop, NEW.picRight, NEW.picBottom, NEW.prnColor, NOW());
END;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_classes
AFTER insert ON Classes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into insert_tracking_classes
        set classID = NEW.classID,
        Title = NEW.Title,
        classDesc = NEW.classDesc,
        Category = NEW.Category,
        isEvent = NEW.isEvent,
        picLeft = NEW.picLeft,
        picTop = NEW.picTop,
        picRight = NEW.picRight,
        picBottom = NEW.picBottom,
        prnColor = NEW.prnColor,
        modified = NOW(); 
END;
```

---

### ERROR

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line * (at the end of the insert/values statement)
```

---

### TRY 2

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_classes AFTER insert ON Classes
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
insert into insert_tracking_classes (classID, Title, classDesc, Category, isEvent, picLeft, picTop, picRight, picBottom, prnColor, modified)
values(NEW.classID, NEW.Title, NEW.classDesc, NEW.Category, NEW.isEvent, NEW.picLeft, NEW.picTop, NEW.picRight, NEW.picBottom, NEW.prnColor, NOW());
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

---

### ERROR

```
    SQL query:

    DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER insert_classes AFTER INSERT ON Classes
    FOR EACH
    ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO insert_tracking_classes( classID, Title, classDesc, Category, isEvent, picLeft, picTop, picRight, picBottom, prnColor, modified )
    VALUES (
-->     NEW.classID, NEW.Title, NEW.classDesc, NEW.Category, NEW.isEvent, NEW.picLeft, NEW.picTop, NEW.picRight, NEW.picBottom, NEW.prnColor, NOW( )
    );

    MySQL said: Documentation
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
         CREATE TRIGGER insert_classes AFTER insert ON Classes
         F' at line 1
```

---

### My Tables

```
CREATE TABLE insert_tracking_classes (  --- Same table layout for Classes table minus Modified time and tracking_id
  tracking_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  classID int(11) NOT NULL,
  Title varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  classDesc text,
  Category varchar(128) default NULL,
  isEvent int(8) default NULL,
  picLeft int(8) default NULL,
  picTop int(8) default NULL,
  picRight int(8) default NULL,
  picBottom int(8) default NULL,
  prnColor varchar(4) default NULL,
  modified datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (tracking_id)
);
```

Update: Have tried to use static values and removing the if and modified = NOW() statements with no change.

Comment: Have you tried creating the triggers one at a time? If yes, could you please elaborate more on where and what the error is?

Comment: yes i have, with same syntax error

Comment: The error only says "syntax error"? Full description of the error might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had to remove Delimiter, Begin, and End statements.

---

### ANSWER

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_classes;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_classes AFTER insert ON Classes
FOR EACH ROW
insert into tracking_classes (command, classID, Title, classDesc, Category, isEvent, picLeft, picTop, picRight, picBottom, prnColor, modified)
values('insert', NEW.classID, NEW.Title, NEW.Desc, NEW.Category, NEW.isEvent, NEW.picLeft, NEW.picTop, NEW.picRight, NEW.picBottom, NEW.prnColor, NOW());
```